# How to customize jsonb field in postgresql to accept 40GB

Tags: postgresql, json, size

**Background**
I am data scientist. I had tried minimize my instance to smaller version, but unfortunately the recalculated result from smaller instance is wrong. After I check with the original value. I found over a thousand values mismatches from the original.

This is impossible for me to catch up thousand variables to match again. Then I have to find tune PostgreSQL

**Question:**
I store my instance in Django JSONField which I guess it is `jsonb` field in Postgres
I am aware that I need to re-compile Postgres from scratch, but I don't mind that.

How can I customize `jsonb` field to accept data size 40GB or more?

Comment: That's a _massive_ change to the architecture of Postgres. But to be honest: if you really need 40GB in a single JSON column, you are using most certainly the wrong approach and data model - at least for a relational database.  It sounds as if you want to store your entire dataset into a single column of a single row, rather than many rows with smaller content. If you can't figure out a better design - maybe even properly normalized - then Postgres is not the right database technology for your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I am considering new approach using FileField since it is write and read. No update in my operation. Tmr I will propose my idea to group meeting.

Comment: Forget it, that won't work. To store data in a relational database, you have to split it into records with a fixed structure.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thank you.